# How can I create a simple menu in Tcl/Tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

When I write anything after

.win configure -menu (something here)

the console shows me the message "invalid command name tk::MenuDup" so I can't go on creating any kind of menu. Where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: We need to know a lot more to be able to help. What kind of window is `.win`? What kind of things have you tried writing after `.menu`? What kind of menu structure are you attempting to build?

Comment: A horizontal menu with items like "File" , "Search", "Help". I don't know why in the examples which are given to me is used .win, I think there is something else to stay. (I'm beginner in programming and almost all is new and complicated for me :) )

Answer (score 4):

Menus *are* fairly hard for the beginner to put together from just the documentation: examples are needed to understand how they work. Once one gets the hang of it, they are actually pretty straightforward.

I don't use menus much myself, so I there might be things I'm forgetting to mention here. I'll do my best, though. Try to read through the menu widget documentation to get feeling for what can be done.

### The basic basics of basic menu management

You need at least one menu widget (several if you are going to have cascading pulldown menus from the menu bar).

```
menu .m
```

Next, add some items to the menu. Command itens are the most common: when selected, they execute a command that you name when adding the item. You also need a label which will be the menu text.

```
.m add command -command filecmd   -label File
.m add command -command searchcmd -label Search
.m add command -command helpcmd   -label Help
```

You need to write the commands too, of course. These are just dummy procedures.

```
proc filecmd {} {tk_messageBox -message Filing!}
proc searchcmd {} {tk_messageBox -message Searching!}
proc helpcmd {} {tk_messageBox -message Helping!}
```

Now we can put the menu in a window. The `.win` window was probably a `toplevel`, i.e. a new independent window created by the running Tk process. We'll instead put the menu in the main window.

```
. configure -menu .m
```

### Once more, with feeling

An example that adds a cascading pulldown menu.

Using dialogs to simulate commands is a bother, I'll add a label that briefly displays a text instead.

```
grid [ttk::label .status -width 30] -sticky ew

proc status txt {
    .status configure -text $txt
    after 1500 [list .status configure -text {}]
}
```

The `status` command just sets the label to show a text, then waits 1.5 seconds and blanks the label again.

Pulldown menus have a 'tear off' feature that lets you drag the menu away and leave it hovering somewhere else on the screen. Tearoff menus were briefly in fashion when Tk was written, so they are on by default. You should always disable the tearoff feature, unless you absolutely want to be able to tear off menus. You can do that by specifying it for individual menus (this menu is just an example of that, you won't need it to run the code below):

```
menu .foobar -tearoff 0
```

You can also change the default setting to 'off' (I strongly suggest you do this):

```
option add *TearOff off
```

Now we create two menus, one main menu for the horizontal bar, and one menu that we can pull down from the first.

```
menu .m
menu .m.file
```

Pull-down menus should be children of the main menu, not siblings as I wrote earlier. Sibling windows work too, but there is probably some level of badness there.

The first menu is similar to the menu in the first example, but the first item is a **cascade** item rather than a command item. That means that instead of calling a command it opens another menu.

```
.m add cascade -menu .m.file      -label File
.m add command -command searchcmd -label Search
.m add command -command helpcmd   -label Help
```

We fill the second menu too...

```
.m.file add command -command {filecmd new}  -label New
.m.file add command -command {filecmd open} -label Open
.m.file add command -command {filecmd save} -label Save
```

We need to create the commands...

```
proc filecmd op {status "File operation {$op} selected"}
proc searchcmd {} {status "Search selected"}
proc helpcmd {} {status "Help selected"}
```

Finally, we add the main menu to the main window. Try it!

```
. configure -menu .m
```

Actually, I think I'll stop here. Apparently, an answer here is supposed to help with a specific question and not be a how-to description. The above should get you started, anyway.

Tk documentation: [grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm), [menu](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/menu.htm), [option](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/option.htm)

Tcl documentation: [after](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/after.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm)

Comment: tl;dr version: Make the menu (even if you don't populate it with content until later) _before_ configuring a toplevel with it. Easy!

Comment: Again: 
cactvs>. configure -menu .m
invalid command name "tk::MenuDup" - 
only when I don't write anything after -menu the console don't show me that message. What can I do?

Comment: @Kristina: I wasn't aware that you were using Cactvs, I thought you were using regular Tcl/Tk. The interpreter and/or library is probably a bit different, requiring other invocations or initializations to set up menus. I am not familiar with Cactvs, so I can't help you further, sorry.

Comment: It's my fault, that I didn't said that I'm using Cactvs, sorry. In the different tutorials and the sites for the console the examples are the same ".win configure -menu .menu.menubar or mbar or menu..." and it didn't works. That's why I look for help from all of you, because you know much more than me and thank you for all information.